# C# test cases for ICloneable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, code-coverage

how to get coverage for `object ICloneable.Clone()` method while writing test cases.

```
 #region ICloneable Members

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }

    public new Blue Clone()
    {
        Blue _temp = (Blue)this.MemberwiseClone();
        _temp.Node = Node.Clone();

        return _temp;
    }

    #endregion
```

The current coverage looks like

[image: the coverage look like].

Comment: You can't just `new` up instance of your class, setting all the properties. Then clone it and assert the values of the properties.  Call it both directly, and via a cast to `IClonable`, casting the result back to your type

Comment: I wish I could modify how the existing function is implemented, but I can't; just need to write test cases. @Flydog57

Comment: I'm describing two tests, not changing the existing code

Comment: okay, you mean like this? 
ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable) blue.Clone();
I tried but didn't cover.

Comment: @RohanNirer `object b = ((ICloneable)blue).Clone();` note that blue is cast to `ICloneable` first before invoking `Clone`. You can always cast back to compare and assert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While these can be separate cases, here is a really simplified example of testing/covering the shown code.

```
//Arrange
Blue expected = new(); //populate as needed

//Act
Blue a = expected.Clone();
Blue b = (Blue)((ICloneable)expected).Clone();

//Assert - using FluentAsertions - cases should be self explanatory 
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b); 
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```